# BTrees: Is there a difference between different TreeSet incarnations?

Tags: python, b-tree

I am looking at the [BTrees](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/BTrees) library and noticed that there are multiple `TreeSet` (and others) classes, e.g.

- `BTrees.IOBTree.TreeSet`
- `BTrees.OOBTree.TreeSet`
- `BTrees.LFBTree.TreeSet`
- ...

I understand that the `BTree` class is different for each one of these as it accepts different types for the keys and values, but how about the `TreeSet` class?

Though trial and error I found that the first letter dictates which types can be held by a `TreeSet` instance, but what about the second letter? Does it have any influence on how the members are stored/retrieved?

Is there any documentation on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the `TreeSet` classes ignore the second letter; they are provided in each `XXBTree` module for completeness and ease of importing.

Under the covers, the modules are created using a lot of creative preprocessor macro work, making it also just easier to produce a `TreeSet` type for each of the key-value type variants.

The package documentation relies in part on [interface definitions](https://github.com/zopefoundation/BTrees/blob/master/BTrees/Interfaces.py); each module has an interface where the first sentence documents what the sets in that package contain:

```
class IIntegerObjectBTreeModule(IBTreeModule, IMerge):
    """keys, or set values, are integers; values are objects.

    describes IOBTree and LOBTree"""
```

and

```
class IIntegerIntegerBTreeModule(IBTreeModule, IIMerge, IMergeIntegerKey):
    """keys, or set values, are integers; values are also integers.

    describes IIBTree and LLBTree"""
```

for example illustrates that for both the `IOBTree` and `IIBTree` modules the set values are integers. As such, `IOBTree.TreeSet` and `IIBTree.TreeSet` are *essentially the same*.

The [package documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/BTrees/) then uses those interface definitions to auto-generate the API docs, including the [per-module documentation with the (tree)set value details](https://pythonhosted.org/BTrees/api.html#BTrees.Interfaces.IObjectObjectBTreeModule).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I looked at the documentation but I found that hard to read from the perspective of a *user* of the library: e.g. it took me a while to figure out that one should simply `from BTrees.XXBTree import XXType` to use the types.

Comment: @FriendFX: a valid and fair point; take into account that this package is nearly 14 years old and for a large part of its existence has been a package internal to the ZODB project; ZODB devs knew how to use it, so why document it further?